# Concurrent communications in MPI with MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE access level

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, mpi

Based on [here](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v4.0/man3/MPI_Init_thread.3.php) and [there](https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report/node303.htm), a developer may use multiple threads in an MPI application to initiate MPI calls without any restrictions, as long as they initiate the MPI application with the `MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE` access level.

Well, MPI forum does not mandate MPI libraries to implement this specification, but if they do, do the MPI communications initiated by the threads run concurrently or not?

Some of the online documentations as well as this [presentation](https://wgropp.cs.illinois.edu/courses/cs598-s15/lectures/lecture36.pdf)(slide 12) suggest that

> When multiple threads make MPI calls concurrently, the outcome will be as if the calls executed sequentially in some (any) order.

If this is true, it means that MPI libraries run all the MPI calls **sequentially** in the background while providing a thread-safe environment to the user. Do all of the MPI libraries (at least the major ones, including MPICH, OpenMPI, MVAPICH,...) handle concurrent MPI calls in this way? Or there exists an MPI library that runs multiple parallel communications *actually* concurrently?

Comment: MPI guarantees that messages between a pair of ranks are non-overtaking, which limits what and when can be communicated. This does not preclude concurrent transport of more than one message at a time, if the network allows it, no matter if the requests are posted sequentially or from multiple threads. Open MPI makes use of multiple network connections if there are multiple interfaces providing connectivity.